# numpy select each row with different lengths

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-3.5

I have two array s

```
x=array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

I want to subselect elements in each row by the length in array y

```
y = array([3, 2, 4])
```

My target is z:

```
z = array([[0, 0, 0],
   [1, 0,],
   [2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

How could I do that with numpy functions instead of list/loop?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Just curious - How do you plan to use such a ragged array?

Comment: Since the result will be a list anyways, a list comprehension is the most direct way of doing the job.

Comment: Or you could use `np.split` and discard every other bit.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy array is optimized for homogeneous array with a specific dimensions. I like to think of it like a matrix: it does not make sense to have a matrix with different number of elements on each rows.

That said, depending on how you want to use the processed array, you can simply make a list of array:

```
z = [array([0, 0, 0]),
array([1, 0,]),
array([2, 2, 2, 2]])]
```

Still, you will need to do that manually:

```
x = array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
y = array([3, 2, 4])

z = [x_item[:y_item] for x_item, y_item in zip(x, y)]
```

The list comprehension iterates over the `x` and `y` combined with `zip()` to create the new slice of the original array.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this also,

```
z = [x[i,:e] for i,e in enumerate(y)]
```